# How to add space between consecutive headings which contains consecutive paragraphs and reduce the space between heading and paragrph

Tags: html, css

I have a multiple headings with consecutive paragraph tags. The space between each paragraph and a heading should be very less where as the space between headings should be very high. I do not want to use div or any class names to tags because i many many heading. below is my code can anyone helo me out.

```css
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

h2,
p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2;
}
```

```html
<h2>heading1</h2>
<p>paragraph1</p>
<h2>heading2</h2>
<p>paragraph2</p>
<h2>heading3</h2>
<p>paragraph3</p>
<h2>heading4</h2>
<p>paragraph4</p>
<h2>heading5</h2>
<p>paragraph5</p>
```

expected output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfJiZ.png)

Comment: `padding: 2` is an invalid value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set the margin between the ehader and the paragraph to 0? You can use the `+` selector to select the next element:

```css
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 + p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>heading1</h2>
<div>paragraph1</p>
<h2>heading2</h2>
<p>paragraph2</p>
<h2>heading3</h2>
<p>paragraph3</p>
<h2>heading4</h2>
<p>paragraph4</p>
<h2>heading5</h2>
<p>paragraph5</p>
```